# Single Sign Out Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a .net core 2.0 mvc app that uses Identity Server 4 to authenticate users. I am having issues with logging the user out of Identity Server and clearing the custom cookie I have created in the mvc app.

In mvc app i trigger logout:

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");
```

I am then redirected to the Identity Server account controller logout action which succesfully produces the "You are now logged out" screen. After this I would like the user to be redirected to the Identity Server login page,
however, when I navigate to my MVC App I am not asked to log in again, but instead I am already authenticated and have access to the mvc app. I am struggling to understand when or how the user is being re-authenticated when I have just logged out.

Below is the code for my startup in MVC and client config in IDSvr4.

**Startup.cs in MVC App**

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {                  
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultForbidScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";               

        })
        .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
        {                
            options.Cookie.Name = "HubCookie";
            options.Cookie.Expiration = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
            options.LogoutPath = "/home/logout";                
        })
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
            options.SignOutScheme = "Cookies";

            options.Authority = "https://auth.test.com/";
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

            options.ClientId = "mvc";
            options.ClientSecret = "XXXXXX";
            options.ResponseType = "code id_token";

            options.SaveTokens = true;
            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

            options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("website", "website");

            options.Scope.Add("api1");
            options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
            options.Scope.Add("testScope");

            options.UseTokenLifetime = true;

            options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:5002/test/";
            //options.CallbackPath = "http://localhost:5002/division/";

});
```

**Client Config in IDSvr4**

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "mvc",
    ClientName = "MVC Client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

    RequireConsent = false,

    ClientSecrets =
    {
        new Secret("XXXXX".Sha256())
    },

    RedirectUris           = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },
    FrontChannelLogoutUri = "http://localhost:5002/home/logout",

    AllowedScopes =
    {
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
        "api1", "testScope"
    },

    AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 300,
    SlidingRefreshTokenLifetime = 120,
    RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
    RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Sliding,
    UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
    AccessTokenLifetime = 60
}
```

Comment: Did you use an external identity provider with identity server?

Comment: No, I am not using any external identity providers.

Comment: Can you post the whole action code with sign out logic?